# Manifest - “Has No Default Constructor” With Activity

Tags: java, android

I've created a button and it's supposed to be when you click on it to open a new activity, but it does not do anything when I press it.

Then I discovered that there was a error in mainfest.xml // How to solve it.
can anyone help me?

This is Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.android.quizapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser == null ){

            Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

This is Startactivity.java

```
    package com.example.android.quizapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mRegBtn;
    public StartActivity(Intent startIntent) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        mRegBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_reg_button);

        mRegBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent reg_intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(reg_intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is Mainifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.quizapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".StartActivity" /> /**<<The Error is here**/
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What do you not understand in *yourclass has no defualt constructor* ? `new StartActivity(startIntent);` - please learn android's basics ... this is not how we start new activity

Comment: You need to remove this `public StartActivity(Intent startIntent){}`

Comment: I deleted it and nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete from your StartActivity the constructor:

```
public StartActivity(Intent startIntent) {

}
```

Comment: I deleted it and nothing happened

Comment: There seem to be other problems with your code as well.

Comment: @MostafaAswany - on stackoverflow.com if an answer helped you solve the problem, make sure to upvote it and mark as "correct answer"

Comment: i try to upvote your answer but,i lost reputation when:
    my question is voted down: −1

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.example.android.quizapp;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser == null ) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(startIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

2nd Module:

```
package com.example.android.quizapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mRegBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        mRegBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_reg_button);

        mRegBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent reg_intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(reg_intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't like to see that someone down voted you so I upvoted you to cancel the effect. Your answer was correct but I don't like a class name StartActivity because the conflict with the method name. Some people don't appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems but the main one is instead of `new StartActivity(startIntent)` try startActivity(startIntent); startActivity is a keyword. Android already has a method by this name so you confused yourself by creating a class with this name. You don't use constructors to launch Activities use intents the callbacks will be called by android as each visual component(view) is measured,referenced,drawn or whatever(the whatever is a black box). Explicit intents are called by class name as you did here so the manifest is good. Don't fix it if it ain't broke.